# Design non-inverting op-amp, with gain = 30estimate Ri, Rf and Rs from the standard 5% resistor value that will meet |AVCL| = 30 within +/-5%tolerance

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design

[image]

I want to Design non-inverting op-amp, with gain = 30 (within +/- 5%) estimate Ri, Rf and Rs from the standard 5% resistor value that will meet |AVCL| = 30 within +/-5% tolerance. I understand how to find the Ri and Rf value using the Gain ratio but for the Rs value is there any considerations to take note or general rule to have a rough estimate of how much it should be? thanks for helping I am trying very hard to find information on how to make a proper estimation on Rs .

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you. But if you tell us which part of this is giving you trouble, we can offer suggestions.

Comment: i do not know what rules to follow to estimate or find value for Rs but i understand how to find the value for Ri and Rf using the Gain.

Comment: @DaveTweed Could you help to explain on the rules or suggestions on how should I choose an optimal value for Rs here? Thanks!

Comment: @mojojo if you think a bit, do you think Rs value depends on Rth or not? If you read the opamp datasheet, does it say how Rs should relate to Ri and Rf? Does it even say if resistances should be in megaohm or milliohm range?

Comment: @Justme I dont think Rs value depends on Rth it should be lower than Xc (meaning CMIC must be a smaller value) impedance value to avoid loading effect

Comment: @mojojo so you think if Rth is for example 10 kilo-ohms, the value of Rs can be 10 ohms or 10 megaohms and it does not affect anything in the circuit? But it does depend on Cmic which is in series with Rth?

Comment: @Justme sorry i tried to digest what you said but i still could not seem to know how i can get the optimal value for Rs i am not trying to ask for answer i just need help or some guidance because i am a beginner in this i am really trying my best to digest and understand sorry if i sound dumb but i am trying

Comment: @mojojo You know that opamps have bias currents. There is a Thevenin equivalent for \$R_f\$ and \$R_i\$. This should suggest to you an area for \$R_s\$. So I imagine, anyway.

Comment: Typically for the inverting configuration, Rs=Rf//Ri is chosen. the non-inverting configuration is incorrect because the left terminal of Ri is floating while it should be grounded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know Rth and Cmic to size the Rs so that you are within your tolerance and frequency limits.

However, there may be other reasons than Rth and Cmic that also limit the values of Rs, and it's up to the op-amp requirements for Rs, and thus it may depend on Ri and Rf, maybe from Cl too.

If you are concerned about noise, the op-amp might have a range for the resistances for least noise.

If you look at the op-amp data sheet, it also shows you an example how to use it with an electret mic.